# URL template parameters not working in APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a scenario:

I want to connect to my backend apis by providing the api endpoints as path.
For eg. apis would look like following

/Measure/Test/Calories?q=*
/Measure/Test/Weight 
/Food/Test/IntakeAmount/ 
/v1/Food/Test/Summary

Though, when I provide the absolute path to api endpoints it do work but providing the endpoints from url template parameters it throws error of **404 Not Found**

Also when I check the trace the inbound request is not able to find the operation:

```
> api-inspector (0.008 ms) {
>     "configuration": {
>         "api": {
>             "from": "/testapi",
>             "to": {
>                 "scheme": "http",
>                 "host": "dev-foodmeasures-summary.com",
>                 "port": 80,
>                 "path": "/",
>                 "queryString": "",
>                 "query": {},
>                 "isDefaultPort": true
>             },
>             "version": null,
>             "revision": "1"
>         },
>         **"operation": "-"**,
>         "user": {
>             "id": "1",
>             "groups": [
>                 "Administrators",
>                 "Developers"
>             ]
>         },
>         "product": {
>             "id": "unlimited"
>         }
>     } }
```

Below is the snapshot for path parameter
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the traces by setting Ocp-Apim-Trace to true. This will add an additional response in the header with the location of your JSON trace file. Just go to that URL and it will potentially provide more insights into the issue.

Comment: I have already enabled that and when it goes to backend it says 

**configuration (0.002 ms)
{
    "message": "Unable to identify Api or Operation for this request. Responding to the caller with 404 Resource Not Found."
}**
Though the backend apis are already present.

Comment: We need to know how you configured your API and operations in APIM. Namely what is API suffix at API level, and what URL template at operations level are set to.